# Kontakt beacon uniqueId sometimes null

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Recently I started playing with a few Kontakt beacons and my Android phone (LG L30).

I added a default region to detect all beacons:

```
private static final Region ALL_BEACONS_REGION = Region.EVERYWHERE;
```

And I initialized a new monitoringListener. The relevant code:

```
    @Override
    public void onBeaconsUpdated(Region region, List<BeaconDevice> list) {
       List<BeaconDevice> beacons = new ArrayList<BeaconDevice>();
       Iterator i = list.iterator();
       while (i.hasNext()){
           BeaconDevice beacon = (BeaconDevice)i.next();
           if(beacon.getUniqueId() != null) {
               beacons.add(beacon);
           }
        }    
  }
```

While debugging I noticed, that sometimes the uniqueId is null. That's why I am checking if it is null, but I still find it very strange. Is that common or is there a mistake in my code? And how can I uniquely identify a beacon if the name is null?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm to check why `getUniqueId()` return `NULL`, we must see how you set this value.

An object you can identify uniquely by using his `hashCode()`. Override this method in the object to generate something uniquely.
see: [overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Or if you want only prevent multiple-entries in the list, you could us a `Set`, which not add duplicates (compared to the your `ArrayList`). 
see: [Java - Set](https://www.google.ch/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java%20set)

Comment: Yes, that would be one option.

Comment: Yes, that would be one option. I don't like looking into the source code of an API, but this time I guess it was a necessity. The uniqueId is part of the advertising package of a beacon and therefore the Android API reads it from the array of bytes it gets, when it gets the advertisement of a beacon. I guess it is a possibility, that the advertisement the device gets is not complete due to signal disturbances, but I rather be sure. I'll keep the question open in case a beacon expert sees it and has an answer.